# pandas read excel from variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to load an excel file.
I get the file from an email attachment using `my_excel_content = email.get_payload(decode=True)` on the body of the email.

I would like to load `my_excel_content` into a pandas dataframe. I could write to it to file and use `read_excel(path)`, but is there any way to load my excel in pandas directly instead of first saving it and loading it anew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) :

> Parameters
> iostr, bytes, ExcelFile, xlrd.Book, path object, or file-like object By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method,
> such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

So something like this should work :

```
from io import BytesIO
data = BytesIO(variable) #variable is supposed to be bytes
df = pd.read_excel(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `StringIO`:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

attachment_content = email.get_payload(decode=True)

s = str(attachment_content, 'utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```